# The meaning of an orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I am reading up on Hilbert spaces and am a bit confused about the properties of an orthogonal basis. Would I be correct in saying that we can define an orthogonal basis as:

1. Every element in the basis is orthogonal to every other.

   2. Every vector in the Hilbert can be written as a linear combination of these vectors.
   3. However, other vectors not in the Hilbert space may also be written as a linear combination of these vectors.

Is this correct, if so how can it be improved and if not why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not a good definition of an orthogonal basis.

1. It's not enough to say every vector can be written as a linear combination, because you may also need **infinite** sums, which are no longer linear combinations.
2. The sentence "other vectors not in the Hilbert space may also be written as a linear combination of these vectors." makes no sense. What are these "other vectors not in the Hilbert space" you speak of? Once you decide to work in a Hilbert space, the elements of that space is *everything* that exists. There **are** no "other vectors".

Comment: See page 7 of this pdf for 'other vectors' http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/infinite.pdf Also can we say that any vector can be written as a infinite sum or linear combination of our basis vectors?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification I see nothing in that pdf that would speak of "other vectors".

Comment: Near the bottom in the paragraph that starts 'One important difference between this type...'

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification I now see the source of your confusion. What that sentence wants to say is that there exist **non-convergent** sums which do not converge to an element of the space. However, those sums may converge if your space is a *subspace* of some other space.